# calling function in class file using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dll, .net-4.0

My database access methods are in class file. This file is has a separate project name: `Usr_mysqladapter`. In another website project I import the class file as a dll and call the function in the class file by creating an object.

The class file contains the following function:

```vb
Public Function readfunctioid(ByVal query As String) As DataTable
    Try
        connecttodb()
        mysqlcmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlcmd)
        dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        disconnect()
    End Try
    Return dt
End Function
```

The website projects imports the dll as follows:

```
  Imports Usr_mysqladapter

  Dim obj As Usr_mysqladapter.Class1 = New Usr_mysqladapter.Class1
```

My button click calls the function like this:

```
dt = obj.readfunctioid("select fld_functionid  from tbl_users_function_permission")
```

Unfortunately, I am getting error. How do I access the function in the class file from my website project?

Comment: Please use complete and well-formed sentences and words. You'll get better results that way. And not just on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, sharing the exact error message with us would help a lot.

Comment: And while I'm at it, your database access code is flawed, in that it forces you to use horribly insecure code to get to your database, because there's not way outside of string concatenation to send query parameters to the database server.

Comment: One more thing: the documentation on the .Fill() method states that it opens and closes the database connection for you, so there is no need for the try/finally in this case...  you know what, I have enough here that I'm gonna move this stuff to an answer, even though it's off topic from the question. You never know... my changes might just side-step your error as a side-effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your website project simply do like.....

```
Dim MyCustomSqlAdapter As = New MyCustomClass()
```

This is when your class is CALLED MyCustomClass
And the INSTANCE is called MyCustomSqlAdapter

Then in button do like....

```
dt = MyCustomSqlAdapter.readfunctioid("select fld_functionid  from tbl_users_function_permission")
```

Answer (score 1):

I started this in the comments to the question, but let me show you the start of a *greatly* improved data access class:

```
Public Class SqlDataHelper

    Private Property ConnectionString() As String
         Get
            'return the connection string, perhaps read/cached from a config file
            'I'll often require this as an argument to the class constructor as well
         End Get
         'May not need a setter, depending on how you build this
    End Property

    Private Function GetConnection() As SqlConnection
         GetConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
         GetConnection.Open()
    End Function

    Private Function GetDataTable(ByVal query As String, ByVal ParamArray args() As SqlParameter) As DataTable
       Dim ds As New DataTable
       Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, GetConnection())     
       If args IsNot Nothing Then
           For Each p As SqlParameter In args
               cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
           Next p
       End If

       Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
       da.Fill(dt)
       Return dt

    End Function

    Private Function UpdateData(ByVal command As String, ByVal ParamArray args() As SqlParameter) As Integer
       Using cn As SqlConnection = GetConnection(), _
             cmd As New SqlCommand(command, cn) 

           If args IsNot Nothing Then
               For Each p As SqlParameter In args
                   cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
               Next p
           End If

           Return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Function

    Private Function GetSingleValue(ByVal query As String, ByVal ParamArray args() As SqlParameter) As Object
       Using cn As SqlConnection = GetConnection(), _
             cmd As New SqlCommand(query, cn) 

           If args IsNot Nothing Then
               For Each p As SqlParameter In args
                   cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
               Next p
           End If

           Return cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    End Function

    Public Function ReadFunctionID() As DataTable  
        Return GetDataTable("SELECT fld_functionid FROM tbl_users_function_permission", Nothing)
    End Function

    Public Function ReadFunctionIDByUser(ByVal UserID As Integer) As DataTable
         Return GetDataTable("SELECT fld_functionid FROM tbl_users_function_permission WHERE UserID = @UserID", _
                    New SqlParameter("@UserID", UserID))
    End Function
End Class
```

Let's take a closer look at some of the improvements in this code. First of all, notice what is Public vs what is Private. At no point do you ever want to accept an ad hoc sql string from the presentation tier. That doesn't mean you can't use ad hoc sql, just that you want to keep your data and presentation sections separate.

Take a look at how the final two functions in the class handle parameter data. The fact that you need to use an explicit `Nothing` when not using any parameters is a *feature* of this code. It's a constant reminder that you should be using query parameters. If you don't know what sql injection is, and how to prevent it, *you shouldn't be writing database code!*

Hopefully this is helpful to you.

Comment: @ Joel Coehoorn thanks for ur code. its very standard. am not able to understand it. thanks for ur reply